# sector size won't change with fdisk

Tags: partition, fdisk, block-device

am trying to change the sector size from 512 to 2048 of my swap partition.

```
# fdisk -b 2048 /dev/mapper/fedora-swap
```

and then I try to write to it gives me the following message.

> The partition table has been altered. Calling ioctl() to re-read
>   partition table. Re-reading the partition table failed.: Invalid
>   argument

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to "dismount" swap with the command

```
swapoff /dev/mapper/fedora-swap
fdisk -b 2048 /dev/mapper/fedora-swap
swapon /dev/mapper/fedora-swap
```

I am not sure about syntax then man swapoff.